# How can i update flask templates without restarting the uwsgi instance?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have a flask application using an uwsgi instance. This application runs some threads in background when a cron command starts. Is there a method for updating my template files without restarting the uwsgi service ?

Currently I'm waiting for my threads to stop and then reloading the uwsgi service.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that. But why don't you use the Flask development server for testing purposes? It can be configured to automatically reload changed templates.

Comment: I have a released application on live and my clients are using it. There are times when I need to update some templates due of custom requests. Minor changes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Enabling `TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD` works nicely:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
```

> Whether to check for modifications of the template source and reload
>   it automatically. By default the value is None which means that Flask
>   checks original file only in debug mode.

Source: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/